# fetching a file from a url for mobile app: How to manage server side running Joomla?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile, joomla

Im new to website development and design so apologize in advance if the question is redundant.

I have a program where a client, using a URL string fetches a XML file from a webserver. This would be no problem right if it were a simple URL with no security or no CMS (like Joomla) involved: Just put the exact URL string and the client gets the file from the web server, done.

But, how would the process work if the URL is on my site hosted on GoDaddy and using a Joomla CMS?

Im trying to understand how the same process of fetching a file works on a hosted server using a CMS. Since I just made the transition from my site being on my school's servers to having a Joomla website Im hosting on goDaddy.

I mean where would I put the file if I also want the file to be accessible only if the client authenticates itself first. Just to be on the safe side. I mean is this how normally things work in mobile apps? I have a client program thats a iPhone app and within the app I have a XML file which is used as a data source for my UITavleView, but I want to check some URL to see if an updated version of the XML file exists. My app side programming is mostly done, now Im trying to learn the server side things I need to do to make this process happen with Joomla and my own hosted site

I donot understand how would the process work in that case. I mean, what are the things I would need to do on the server side to and the client side to make this possible?

Please help me understand or if you could point me to some links where these steps are illustrated...or if you could give me some Google key words I can search for to learn about this process.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you have a CMS does not generally change how you access a file within the file structure of your domain unless the CMS protects certain directories. In this case, Joomla does not so you can directly access any file you wish. Depending on the sensitivity of the information you are trying to retrieve, you can protect the directory through your domain management panel. If it's not particularly sensitive, the authentication can be done by the app since the URL you are accessing can be easily hidden from the user.

It seems like that would be the simplest solution since the app will have access to user information by nature of where it resides.